# python factory method relative to the instance itself, (class method also using self as argument?)

Tags: python, oop, factory, class-method

So I have this piece of code originally,

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val:int):
        self.val = val

    def next(self) -> Foo:
        """
        Returns:
            Foo: Foo with value 1 bigger than the current
        """
        return Foo(self.val+1)
```

which, the next() method is to generate another Foo instance based on the current instance.

It works fine so far, but then I have read about static method and class method in python, and it seemed that I might should using a class method for `next()`, as it is a factory method (please point out if I got the idea wrong!)

What would be the most elegant way to implement the above?

Comment: Since it is using information contained in `self`, it seems suitable for an instance method.

Comment: It's not clear how you would use a static method for this since you would not have the instance's state (i.e `self.val`).

Comment: @khelwood, I see what you mean here, I thought that all "factory method" should be a class method, but now it seemed that since it uses information from the instance, it should be remain as an instance method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
class Foo:
    index = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = Foo.index
        Foo.index += 1
```

Now, you just have to do:

```
zero = Foo()
one = Foo()
```

And if you want to force a starting value:

```
Foo.index = 99
n99 = Foo()
n100 = Foo()
```